# Access javascript function in PHP for shell command

Tags: javascript, php, abi

I am using PHP to execute shell commands to a `Geth` console (Geth runs javascript), to achieve a similar result to the answer in [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26672/how-do-i-transfer-erc20-tokens-gnt-omg-etc-from-a-cold-wallet-to-another-acco) question.

**First, I must create an ERC20 contract variable using the web3 contract method:**

```
 $command = "sudo geth --exec ". '"'."web3.eth.contract(".json_encode($omisegoAbi).").at('0xd26114cd6EE289AccF82350c8d8487fedB8A0C07')".'"'." attach ipc://root/.ethereum/geth.ipc";
 $result = shell_exec($command);
```

The value of `$result` is shown below:

> { abi: [{ constant: true, inputs: [], name: "mintingFinished", outputs: [{...}], payable: false, type: "function" }, { constant: true, inputs: [], name: "name", outputs: [{...}], payable: false, type: "function" }, { constant: false, inputs: [{...}, {...}], name: "approve", outputs: [], payable: false, type: "function" }, { constant: true, inputs: [], name: "totalSupply", outputs: [{...}], payable: false, type: "function" }, { constant: false, inputs: [{...}, {...}, {...}], name: "transferFrom", outputs: [], payable: false, type: "function" }, { constant: true, inputs: [], name: "decimals", outputs: [{...}], payable: false, type: "function" }, { constant: false, inputs: [], name: "unpause", outputs: [{...}], payable: false, type: "function" }, { constant: false, inputs: [{...}, {...}], name: "mint", outputs: [{...}], payable: false, type: "function" }, { constant: true, inputs: [], name: "paused", outputs: [{...}], payable: false, type: "function" }, { constant: true, inputs: [{...}], name: "balanceOf", outputs: [{...}], payable: false, type: "function" }, { constant: false, inputs: [], name: "finishMinting", outputs: [{...}], payable: false, type: "function" }, { constant: false, inputs: [], name: "pause", outputs: [{...}], payable: false, type: "function" }, { constant: true, inputs: [], name: "owner", outputs: [{...}], payable: false, type: "function" }, { constant: true, inputs: [], name: "symbol", outputs: [{...}], payable: false, type: "function" }, { constant: false, inputs: [{...}, {...}], name: "transfer", outputs: [], payable: false, type: "function" }, { constant: false, inputs: [{...}, {...}, {...}], name: "mintTimelocked", outputs: [{...}], payable: false, type: "function" }, { constant: true, inputs: [{...}, {...}], name: "allowance", outputs: [{...}], payable: false, type: "function" }, { constant: false, inputs: [{...}], name: "transferOwnership", outputs: [], payable: false, type: "function" }, { anonymous: false, inputs: [{...}, {...}], name: "Mint", type: "event" }, { anonymous: false, inputs: [], name: "MintFinished", type: "event" }, { anonymous: false, inputs: [], name: "Pause", type: "event" }, { anonymous: false, inputs: [], name: "Unpause", type: "event" }, { anonymous: false, inputs: [{...}, {...}, {...}], name: "Approval", type: "event" }, { anonymous: false, inputs: [{...}, {...}, {...}], name: "Transfer", type: "event" }], address: 1.201053046308259e+48, transactionHash: null, Approval: function(), Mint: function(), MintFinished: function(), Pause: function(), Transfer: function(), Unpause: function(), allEvents: function(), allowance: function(), approve: function(), balanceOf: function(), decimals: function(), finishMinting: function(), mint: function(), mintTimelocked: function(), mintingFinished: function(), name: function(), owner: function(), pause: function(), paused: function(), symbol: function(), totalSupply: function(), transfer: function(), transferFrom: function(), transferOwnership: function(), unpause: function() }

**The next step is to check the account balance of this contract**

My understanding is that this is a **javascript object**, and I need to run one of the functions that this object has, named `balanceOf`.

How do I create a shell command in PHP, that passes this function? Here is what I have so far.

Because `$result` is a string, I cannot access the `balanceOf` function, I instead receive an error. Because `$result` is not JSON, I cannot simply decode the string and use the functions normally:

> $balance = "sudo geth --exec ". '"'."web3.fromWei(".$result->balanceOf('0xb8fd65fc6919c5b97453eaba6b895144597985b2').")".'"'." attach ipc://root/.ethereum/geth.ipc";

Comment: Looks like a json ... so `json_decode()` ?

Comment: It is sadly not JSON because there are no quotation marks

Comment: He is trying to access a function, not parse the response

Comment: Seems like the result does not contain functions bodies, so You won't be able to run those functions even if You hand the result over to some JS engine.

Comment: Are you asking how to first call a js function through CLI and then run methods on the object you get back using PHP?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson yes I think that's right. I am essentially trying to do the answer in this question here, but in PHP https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26672/how-do-i-transfer-erc20-tokens-gnt-omg-etc-from-a-cold-wallet-to-another-acco

Comment: That didn't really help me. Can you please edit your question to include a proper flow (step by step) of what you're trying to do and where you run into issues? That way, we can remove any guess work and assumptions.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thanks for the help, I have added some more detail on what I'm trying to achieve, please let me know if you need more info

Comment: `Access javascript function in PHP` - you can't do that